# Power spectral density (PSD) of a two-dimensional linear stochastic differential equation (SDE) with additive noise

Tags: stochastic-processes, fourier-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, fast-fourier-transform

I am considering a two-dimensional linear SDE of the form
$$\begin{cases}
dX_1 =\bigl(A_{11} X_1 + A_{12} X_2 \bigr)\,dt + \sigma \,dW_1,
\\
dX_2 =\bigl(A_{21} X_1 + A_{22} X_2 \bigr)\,dt + \sigma \,dW_2,
\end{cases} $$
where $W_1$ and $W_2$ are one-dimensional Wiener processes, the $A_{ij}$ are real, and so is $\sigma$.

My goal is to get an expression for the PSD of $X_1$. I have looked at both suggestions in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1647793/how-to-calculate-the-psd-of-a-stochastic-process) but I am unable to apply them to my problem. Having two Wiener processes $W_1$ and $W_2$ (instead of one as in the referenced post) throws me off. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2795608/532409   ...is it possible to apply the same method?