# Probability density function (PDF) of a two-dimensional linear stochastic differential equation (SDE) with additive noise

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I am considering the same two-dimensional linear SDE as [in a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3997216/power-spectral-density-psd-of-a-two-dimensional-linear-stochastic-differential):

\begin{cases}
dX_1 =\bigl(A_{11} X_1 + A_{12} X_2 \bigr)\,dt + \sigma \,dW_1,
\\
dX_2 =\bigl(A_{21} X_1 + A_{22} X_2 \bigr)\,dt + \sigma \,dW_2,
\end{cases}

where $W_1$ and $W_2$ are one-dimensional Wiener processes, the $A_{ij}$ are real, and so is $\sigma$.

Is a there a way to obtain an analytical expression for the (unconditional) PDF of $X_1$? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your process essentially is a 2d Ornstein- Uhlenbeck process. I would expect that you can find a closed expression for the joint distribution in the literature. The density for the first marginal you then get by integrating out the second component.

Comment: Thanks, I will look more closely at the literature.

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer in the literature? if so, may you share some links that you found useful?